# Specify different snapcraft output folder

Tags: snap

I am taking my first steps with snapcraft, and each time I am running `snapcraft` in a folder with `snapcraft.yaml`, it generates all the build, stage, prime folders.

Is there a way to specify that I want these folders to be tucked away inside one folder (like ./tmp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really instruct snapcraft to create folders in a specific place, but if you use Snapcraft 3 and specify a base in your `snapcraft.yaml` (such as `base: core18`), builds will be executed in a segregated environment and those folders won't be created on your host environment (the one you run `snapcraft` from). If you just need them out of the way, this should solve your problem.

Edit: there's [a forum post](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/out-of-tree-builds-with-snapcraft/9830) detailing a patch proposal that might do exactly what you want.